# how can i hide music address in web player?

Tags: stream, html5-audio

How can I hide music address (music/stream.mp3)?

I don't want the listener to see the address of music and can download this!
I have a website for music stream and listener should not be able to download the music.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="music/stream.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Do I have to change the format or what?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is impossible.

You cannot send data someone, expect them to decode it, and at the same time prevent them from decoding it.

Obfuscating a URL isn't going to do anything... it's trivial just to open your browser developer tools, debugging proxies, packet capture, or one of the hundreds of browser extensions to snag the source of the media and then download it.  Even if you built your own transport mechanism, you still have to get that audio data to the browser to be played and a script can be easily injected to get it.

Don't bother with this.

What you *can* do is make URLs that are signed so that they only work for authorized users, and for a certain time period.  If you're using something like S3 or a similar service, this is very easy to do.  This doesn't prevent anyone from downloading stuff, but it will prevent your entire library from usefully ending up on a search engine... that is until someone downloads it and uploads it elsewhere.

What you have is a legal problem, not a technical one.